# Java >>> Operator

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between >>> and >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)

Could someone explain what the `>>>` operator does in in Java.
I encountered it in this question, [Hash method in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176031/hash-method-in-hashmap). From its usage in the question it appears to be a shift operator - what's the difference between `>>>` and `>>`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: google: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

Comment: +1 Java needs this operator because `int` and `long` types are signed. It doesn't need an unsigned left shift because that would do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the difference with a simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    int i = -1;
    int j = i >> 1;
    int k = i >>> 1;
    System.out.println("i = " + i + "\t\t<=> " + Integer.toBinaryString(i));
    System.out.println("j = " + j + "\t\t<=> " + Integer.toBinaryString(j));
    System.out.println("k = " + k + "\t<=> " + Integer.toBinaryString(k));
}
```

output:

```
i = -1          <=> 11111111111111111111111111111111  
j = -1          <=> 11111111111111111111111111111111  
k = 2147483647  <=> 1111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: from where does this number 2147483647 come from?

Comment: The largest positive integer (all bits at 1 except the sign bit which is the left most one).

Answer (score 0):

the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right.The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position,

more information

[Follow this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)